# MongoDB: convert existing json string to json object

Tags: json, mongodb, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an existing `json string` field to `json array/object` as I have recently moved data from `mysql` to `mongodb`.

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63f241012a9551202e909257"
  },
  "title": "Jumanji: Welcome To The Jungle",
  "description": "...",
  ...
  "info": "[{\"year\": \"2017\", ... },{\"year\": \"2019\", ... }]",
  ...
}
```

I need this to be

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63f241012a9551202e909257"
  },
  "title": "Jumanji: Welcome To The Jungle",
  "description": "...",
  ...
  "info": [{
    "year": 2017, 
    ... 
  }, {
    "year": 2019, 
    ... 
  }],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Where do you want the conversion to occur?  ... in a file?  ... in python? ... in MongoDB document?

Comment: Directly in mongo-shell.

Comment: If `doc` is currently assigned to the object you show, does `doc.info = JSON.parse(doc.info)` give what you are looking for?

Comment: Perhaps better would be [`doc.info = EJSON.parse(doc.info)`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#extended-json-methods).

Comment: Could you given me an example for that. I am kind of new at this, so its not getting to me. Like `db.movies.updateMany(...)`

Comment: Ahhh, so this is already a document in a MongoDB collection?  I thought it was just assigned to a variable in `mongosh`.  So you need an update operation on your collection?

Comment: Yes. I have inserted all the data into mongodb but the `info` was previously saved as json string in mysql table and I am trying to convert it into json in mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to convert your JSON string by letting Javascript `parse` it.

```js
db.movies.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "info": {
        "$function": {
          "lang": "js",
          "args": ["$info"],
          "body": "function(infoStr) {return JSON.parse(infoStr)}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/orfsnRSSifq).

Comment: Ok, let me try this

Comment: Thank you, It worked... I had been struggling with this for hours. Many thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome.  It's unfortunate the export/import process didn't go smoother.

Comment: Thank you, but this is just one of many hurdles which I still have to face.

Answer (score 2):

With reference to @rickhg12hs solution, below is another way to perform the same task.

```js
db.movies.updateMany({}, [{
  $set: {
    info: {
      $function: {
        lang: "js",
        args: ["$info"],
        body: "function(infoStr) { return JSON.parse(infoStr); }"
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

Also, please keep that in mind that the `arrow function syntax` is not supported in this scenario. So, always use `function` notations to perform such operations.

Comment: This worked flawlessly!  I am actually using this same command but from Node.js to handle a migration.  Good stuff!